# Handler in android giving error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am using handler in my code to update the app on every specific time interval.

For that i written follwing code:

```
public class Messages extends Activity {


    protected Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_messages);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        String id = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_ID);
        String[] lst = null;
        ListView lm=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        tv.setText("Welcome " + message);

        handler.postDelayed(new UpdateTask(),500);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.messages, menu);
        return true;
    }

    class UpdateTask implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_messages);

            Intent intent = getIntent();

            String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
            String id = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_ID);
            String[] lst = null;
            ListView lm=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            tv.setText("Welcome " + message);

            CallSoap cs=new CallSoap();

            lst=cs.GetMessage(id);

            ArrayAdapter<String> adpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lst);

            lm.setAdapter(adpt);

            handler.postDelayed(this, 500);
        }

    }


}
```

But it is giving me error on :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lst);
```

Text: `Constructor ArrayAdapter is undefined.`

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Messages.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lst);
```

But i don't understand why you put all those inside a handler.

Also i see `setContentView` twice for the same activity which is not a good design.

If you need to update the listview update the underlying data that populates listview and call `notifyDataSetchanged` on your adapter.

Also `setContentView` and intializing views everytime is not a good idead

Comment: i want to refresh or rexecute this code after specific time interval each time thats why

Comment: @NavatKayAahe what you are doing does not look to be a good design to me

Comment: then what should i do, i am really new with this, plz guid me.

Comment: yup, i just tested and its working for me..besides code design which i will update in my app

Comment: @NavatKayAahe but still even if it working if you need to update lsitview what your doing is not a good approach. just update the underlying data that populates lsitview and call `notifDataSetChanged` on your adapter no need to `setContentView` and initialize views everytime

Answer (score 1):

Relace "this" reference in the constructor with ActivityName.this.

Changing

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lst);
```

to

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Messages.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lst);
```

should work.

That being said, if you are looking for periodic update only, then the above code need not be necessary to be called all the times.

Instead simply calling  `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` should do the work,.

Answer (score 1):

you shold change this

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lst);
```

by

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(YourActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lst);
```